# What does ifup do when "/etc/network/interfaces" has an invalid netmask address?

Tags: networking, ip, embedded, busybox

The interfaces file looks like below:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.130
    netmask 250.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.254
```

As you can see the netmask address is sort of invalid. (250 instead of 255)
The problem is when we use the following code to get the current IP address and netmask:

```
ioctl(iSock, SIOCGIFADDR, &stIFReq);
ioctl(iSock, SIOCGIFNETMASK, &stIFReq);
```

It **always** returns "**72,0,67,33**" (hex:0x48004321) on both ioctl functions.
I wonder if this is some sort of error code or bug during `ifup`. I would like to know what type of checking `ifup` does on netmasks/ip addresses and what does it do if the address is judged as invalid.

Additional info:

1. Linux version 2.6.35.3
2. BusyBox v1.18.5
3. [ifup] is not a script but a C program on the system

Answer (score 2):

Check on your system, but on most `ifup` is a shell script, so you can see what it does by taking a peak at the source. You can see where the script resides with this command:

```
$ type -a ifup
ifup is /sbin/ifup
```

#### Feodra/Red Hat Distros

On my system (Fedora 14) `/sbin/ifup` includes this library of shell script functions, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions`. If you `grep` through this file for "mask":

```
$ grep -i mask /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions
    if [ -z "${NETMASK}" ]; then
    eval $(/bin/ipcalc --netmask ${IPADDR})
    eval $(/bin/ipcalc --prefix ${IPADDR} ${NETMASK})
    eval $(/bin/ipcalc --broadcast ${IPADDR} ${NETMASK})
    eval $(/bin/ipcalc --network ${IPADDR} ${NETMASK})
```

The tool `ipcalc` is an executable that is used to do "calculations" regarding network configurations.

You can run it from the command line too:

```
$ /bin/ipcalc --netmask 192.168.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0

$ /bin/ipcalc --prefix 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
PREFIX=24
```

#### Debian/Ubuntu

The `ipcalc` tool is slightly different on Debian/Ubuntu but serves a similar function.

```
$ ipcalc 192.168.1.1
Address:   192.168.1.1          11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000001
Netmask:   255.255.255.0 = 24   11111111.11111111.11111111. 00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.255            00000000.00000000.00000000. 11111111
=>
Network:   192.168.1.0/24       11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000000
HostMin:   192.168.1.1          11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000001
HostMax:   192.168.1.254        11000000.10101000.00000001. 11111110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.255        11000000.10101000.00000001. 11111111
Hosts/Net: 254                   Class C, Private Internet
```

#### You configurations

*Fedora:*

```
$ /bin/ipcalc --netmask 192.168.0.130
NETMASK=255.255.255.0

$ /bin/ipcalc --prefix 192.168.0.130 250.255.255.0
PREFIX=24
```

*Ubuntu:*

```
$ ipcalc 192.168.0.130
Address:   192.168.0.130        11000000.10101000.00000000. 10000010
Netmask:   255.255.255.0 = 24   11111111.11111111.11111111. 00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.255            00000000.00000000.00000000. 11111111
=>
Network:   192.168.0.0/24       11000000.10101000.00000000. 00000000
HostMin:   192.168.0.1          11000000.10101000.00000000. 00000001
HostMax:   192.168.0.254        11000000.10101000.00000000. 11111110
Broadcast: 192.168.0.255        11000000.10101000.00000000. 11111111
Hosts/Net: 254                   Class C, Private Internet
```

So what's most likely happening is your settings are getting setup with the wrong value in a spot. To debug this further I'd need to see the output of `ip`.

#### Example

```
$ ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:19:d1:e8:4c:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.3/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::219:d1ff:fee8:4c95/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. Sorry I didn't put it earlier but [ifup] on the system is not a script, but a program. Also, the system is on an embedded device so, it lacks some command/functions like [ipcalc].

Comment: @NazeKimi - figures. What does `ifup` show you? It should be a text file that you can view with a `more` command.

Comment: here was the output

Comment: `[root]# ifup -a
ifup: interface lo already configured
ifup: interface eth0 already configured
[root]#
[root]#
[root]# ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:06:48:00:43:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[root]#`

Comment: @NazeKimi - sorry I meant for you to more the file, not run it.

Comment: `more` returns an error. says it's not a text file

Comment: @NazeKimi - can you run `file` against the file `ifup`? You need to give it a full path to it.

Comment: It seems the system has no `file` command

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` indicates that this is Debian's `ifup`, not Red Hat. They are programs with the same name and general purpose but completely different syntax and behavior. Debian's `ifup` is not a shell script.

Comment: @Gilles - thanks, I wasn't sure how different these were, I guess they're very different, I'll look into Debian/Ubuntu, and try to provide additional guidance.

Comment: @NazeKimi - does you install have the tool `ipcalc`? According to the BusyBox docs (http://www.busybox.net/BusyBox.html) a version of `ipcalc` similar to what I showed above should be present. Can you please confirm? If so also please run the commands using `ipcalc` and report the options in your Q.

Comment: @slm - thanks, I will try if I can install `ipcalc` this and add the results to the OP

Comment: @slm, I seem to be having problems installing `ipcalc`. Can you point me to the right website where I can download the `ipcalc` script/program?

Comment: @NazeKimi - what's the distro you're using here? `lsb_release -a` should tell you this.

Comment: @slm, there wasn't a `lsb_release` command, but the distro is ubuntu

Comment: @NazeKimi - if it's Ubuntu then this should install it, `sudo apt-get install ipcalc`.

Comment: @slm, there is also no `apt-get` command on the system. Is there no way to just download `ipcalc` somewhere? The embedded device is really running on a very sized-down kernel version. thanks

Comment: @NazeKimi - http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ipcalc

Answer (score 2):

You are running BusyBox, where`ifup`/`ifdown` are applets. Looking at function `count_netmask_bits()` in the [source code](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/ifupdown.c), BusyBox starts at the LSB and stops when it encounters the first 1. So it will not notice your malformed netmask.